# Experiences with message based master-worker frameworks (Java/Python/.Net)

Tags: repository, osgi, nservicebus, rabbitmq, celery

I am designing a distributed master-worker system which, from 10,000 feet, consists of:

- Web-based UI
- a master component, responsible for generating jobs according to a configurable set of algorithms
- a set of workers running on regular pc's, a HPC cluster, or even cloud
- a digital repository
- messaging based middleware
- different categories of tasks, with running times ranging from < 1s to ~6hrs.  Tasks are computation heavy, rather than data/IO heavy.  The volume of tasks is not expected to be great (as far as I can see now).  Probably maxing around 100/min.

Strictly speaking there is no need to move outside of the Windows ecosystem but I would be more comfortable with a cross-platform solution to keep options open (nb. some tasks are Windows only).

I have pretty much settled on [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as a messaging layer and [Fedora-commons](http://www.fedora-commons.org) seems to be the most mature off-the-shelf repository.  As for the master/worker logic I am evaluating:

- Java-based: [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) + Postgres + [DOSGi](http://coderthoughts.blogspot.com/2009/02/distributed-osgi-simple-example.html) or [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/) with
  [Zookeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/)
- Python-based: [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) + Postgres + [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)
- .net-based: [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) + SQL Server + [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com) + Sharepoint or [Zentity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/zentity/) as the repository

I have looked at various IoC/DI containers but doubt they are really the best fit for a task execution container and add extra layers/complexity.  But maybe I'm wrong.

Currently I am leaning towards the python solution (keep it lightweight) but I would be interested in any experiences/suggestions people have to share, particularly with the .net stack.  Open source/scalability/resilience features are plus points.

PS: A more advanced future requirement will be the ability for the user to connect directly to a running task (using a web UI) and influence its behaviour (real-time steering).  A direct communication channel will be needed to do this (doing this over AMQP does not seem like a good idea).

Comment: Update: After settling on RabbitMQ as broker and protobuf as the serialization library we decided to go down the python route since it seems to be the best 'glue' to keep everything together.  Will report back as the project progresses.

Answer (score 0):

Dirk

With respect to the master / worker logic and the Java option.

Nimble (see http://www.paremus.com/products/products_nimble.html) with its OSGi Remote Services stack might provide an interesting / agile pure OSGi approach. You still have to decided on a specific distribution mechanism. But given that the USe Case is computationally heavy & data-lite, using the Essence RMI transport that ships with Nimble RSA with a simple front end load balancer function might work really well.

An good approach to 'direct communication channel' - would be to leverage DDS - this a low latency Publication / Subscription peer to peer messaging standard - used in distributed command/control type environments. I think there is a bare-bones OSS project somewhere but we (Paremus) work with RTI in this area.

Hope the above is of background interest.

Comment: thanks I came across Paremus during my initial exploration, will take a closer look